# Discord.js DiscordAPIError: Interaction has already been acknowledged

Tags: javascript, discord.js

When I run the code without buttons, it run perfectly but when I add buttons I get this error: `DiscordAPIError: Interaction has already been acknowledged.`.
Here is my code:

```js
async execute(interaction) {
    if(!interaction.isCommand()) return;

    const getChoices = interaction.options.getString('ne_öğrenmek_istersin'); 

    if(getChoices === 'popüler') {
        if (!interaction.isButton())
        moviedb
            .moviePopular({ language: 'tr'})
            .then(async (res) => {
        const cizgi = '`'
        const num = Math.floor(Math.random () * 3)

        const row = new MessageActionRow()
            .addComponents(
                new MessageButton()
                    .setCustomId('red')
                    .setLabel('')
                    .setStyle('PRIMARY'),
            )
            .addComponents(
                new MessageButton()
                    .setCustomId('orange')
                    .setLabel('')
                    .setStyle('PRIMARY'),
            )
            .addComponents(
                new MessageButton()
                    .setCustomId('blue')
                    .setLabel('')
                    .setStyle('PRIMARY'),
            )
            .addComponents(
                new MessageButton()
                    .setCustomId('green')
                    .setLabel('')
                    .setStyle('PRIMARY'),
            );

        const embed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#f4900c')
            .setThumbnail(`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/${res.results[num].poster_path}`)
            .setTimestamp() // zamanı yazdırıyor
            .setTitle('Popüler Filmler')
            .addFields(
              {name: ` __${res.results[0].title}__`, value: `>>> ${cizgi}${res.results[0].release_date}${cizgi} ${cizgi}${res.results[0].vote_average}${cizgi}  ${res.results[0].original_language}`, inline: true},
              {name: ` __${res.results[1].title}__`, value: `>>> ${cizgi}${res.results[1].release_date}${cizgi} ${cizgi}${res.results[1].vote_average}${cizgi}  ${res.results[1].original_language}`, inline: true},
              {name: `\u200B`, value: `\u200B`},
              {name: ` __${res.results[2].title}__`, value: `>>> ${cizgi}${res.results[2].release_date}${cizgi} ${cizgi}${res.results[2].vote_average}${cizgi}  ${res.results[2].original_language}`, inline: true},
              {name: ` __${res.results[3].title}__`, value: `>>> ${cizgi}${res.results[3].release_date}${cizgi} ${cizgi}${res.results[3].vote_average}${cizgi}  ${res.results[3].original_language}`, inline: true},
              {name: 'Filmler Hakkında Detaylı Bilgi İçin Alttaki Butonları Kullanabilirsiniz', value: '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------'},
            );
        const filter = i => i.customId === 'red' || 'orange' || 'blue' || 'green';

        const collector = await interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({ filter, time: 15000 });

        collector.on('collect', async i => {
            if (i.customId === 'red') {
                var tırnak = '`'
                var space = ' ' 
                const redEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
                    .setColor('DARK_GOLD')
                    .setThumbnail(`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original${res.results[0].poster_path}`) 
                    .setImage(`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original${res.results[0].backdrop_path}`)
                    .setTitle(`Film`)
                    .setDescription(`__**${res.results[0].title}**__`)
                    .addFields(
                      { name: `Film Hakkında Bilgiler\n----------------------------`, value: `**Orjinal İsmi:** ${tırnak}${res.results[0].original_title}${tırnak}\n${space}\n**Orjinal Dili:** ${tırnak}${res.results[0].original_language}${tırnak} **Yapım Yılı:** ${tırnak}${res.results[0].release_date}${tırnak} **Puanı:**${tırnak}☆ ${res.results[0].vote_average}${tırnak}`},
                    )
                    .addField(`Özet:`,`${tırnak}${res.results[num].overview}${tırnak}`);
                
                await i.update({ embeds: [redEmbed], components: []});
            }

            else if(i.customId === 'orange') {
                var tırnak = '`'
                var space = ' ' 
                const redEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
                    .setColor('DARK_GOLD')
                    .setThumbnail(`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original${res.results[1].poster_path}`) 
                    .setImage(`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original${res.results[1].backdrop_path}`)
                    .setTitle(`Film`)
                    .setDescription(`__**${res.results[1].title}**__`)
                    .addFields(
                      { name: `Film Hakkında Bilgiler\n----------------------------`, value: `**Orjinal İsmi:** ${tırnak}${res.results[1].original_title}${tırnak}\n${space}\n**Orjinal Dili:** ${tırnak}${res.results[1].original_language}${tırnak} **Yapım Yılı:** ${tırnak}${res.results[1].release_date}${tırnak} **Puanı:**${tırnak}☆ ${res.results[1].vote_average}${tırnak}`},
                    )
                    .addField(`Özet:`,`${tırnak}${res.results[1].overview}${tırnak}`);
                
                await i.update({ embeds: [redEmbed], components: []});
            }

        });

        collector.on('end', collected => console.log(`Collected ${collected.size} items`));
            await interaction.reply({embeds: [embed], components: [row]})
        })
    }
    else if(getChoices === 'vizyondakiler') {
        await interaction.reply('Vizyondakiler !')
    }
}
```

I think this error async-await sourced but i use async-await i don't know what is causing this problem

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `collecter.on()` function you have

```
await i.update({ embeds: [redEmbed], components: []});
```

even though you havent replied to the interaction in the first place.

Try switching the update to reply.

Comment: its not help just reply message, and then get `Interaction has already been acknowledged.` error

Comment: replace with 'reply' and:
https://www.hizliresim.com/mjhprxm
https://www.hizliresim.com/8xob3mi
i get this error again `DiscordAPIError: Interaction has already been acknowledged.`